# nested max() function in a hql query

Tags: hibernate, hql

I want max((select max(c1) from t1 where cond1)), (select max(c2) from t2 where cond2), c3 from t3 where cond3). Is there a way to obtain this using hibernate/hql ?

I've tried with union:

```
SELECT MAX(date_val) AS dbDate
FROM (
  SELECT MAX(ctl.changeDate) AS date_val FROM contents ctl WHERE ctl.isApproved = true
  UNION ALL
  SELECT MAX(state.changeDate) AS date_val FROM states state WHERE state.status = 'COMPLETED'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT sl.changeDate AS date_val FROM record rec INNER JOIN seeds sl WHERE sl.isLast = true
) subquery
```

but I keep receiving:

```
Stacktrace follows:
Message: unexpected token: ( near line 3, column 6 [
SELECT MAX(date_val) AS dbDate
FROM (
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the most *elegant* approach is to use a `union`:

```
select max(w) from (select x as w from X union select y as w from Y)
```

If you would like something closer to your original query, you could use:

```
select greatest((select max(x) from X), (select max(y) from Y))
```

I do not know which of those queries performs better, however. Better check your query plan!

Nice question!

##### UPDATE

Note that the above queries will only work in Hibernate 6. Time to upgrade :-)

Comment: I've tried with union but I keep receiving a syntax error. I've updated the description if you want to see.

Comment: You might not be using Hibernate 6. My queries were written using new features of HQL in Hibernate 6.